# SharePoint Embed web part re-writing my URL

Tags: sharepoint-online

SharePoint Online:  Until yesterday, I was able to use the standard Embed web part to display an iFrame to my SSRS Report server that included the control settings in the URL to hide toolbar, etc.

Like this:

```
<iframe src="https://reports.mydomain.com/ReportServer?/Reports/WallChart_GP&rs:Command=Render&rc:Toolbar=false&rs:ClearSession=true" height="400" width="300"></iframe>
```

Today, that is suddenly resulting in "Reporting Server Error:  The operation you are attempting on item '/' is not allowed for this item type. (rsWrongItemType)".  However if I put the URL directly into a browser I get the correct result... report with no toolbar.

When I switch the SharePoint page to edit mode and look at the Embed web part, I see that it's changing my & to & plus "amp;" for HTML formatting.  If I paste that modified string into a separate browser I do still reach the report but the server ignores at least some of my commands in that I then see the report server toolbar despite setting it to false.  So I don't know if it's always changed my URL like that, or if that is indeed the source of my problem.  But I had not even re-published my pages in SharePoint.

If I put an embed string in the SharePoint web part that does not attempt these report server commands, I do get the report as desired.  For example this displays my report in the SharePoint web part (but with the toolbar that I'm trying to avoid showing):

```
<iframe src="https://reports.mydomain.com/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fReports%2fWallChart_GP" height="400" width="300"></iframe>
```

The thing that has me bring this here is the fact that it was working up until yesterday.  Nothing was changed on either end.  I suppose Microsoft Support may be the correct avenue but I'm concerned that I will just be told that I can't do it without regard to the fact that it worked all along.

Any insight into why this is now different or what I can do to resolve the problem?

Comment: you ccannot use `/` behind `?`. Are you sure you copied the URL correctly?

Comment: Martin thanks for the attention to this.  Yes I can see that this is correct.  This article shows examples of doing exactly that:  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/access-report-server-items-using-url-access?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use a pre-built application in ShP.. In my experience with code snippets I'm trying to find other ways than this one.